# Is it possible to use a reference to some function's call attribute and pass it around as a value?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, first-class-functions

This doesn't work:

```
-> f = Number.prototype.toLocaleString.call
<- ƒ call() { [native code] }
-> typeof f
<- "function"
-> f(1)
<- Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is it possible to reference and use some function's `call` "method" and use it as a regular function?

Comment: The `typeof f === "function"` really baffles me...

Comment: The `.call` property of *any* function is exactly the same as that of any other function. Also I don't get that error; I get a complaint that `.call()` is invoked with a `this` value that isn't a function (which is what I'd expect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *any* function's `call` property is equivalent to `Function.prototype.call`, which cannot be called on its own, without a calling context:

```js
console.log(Number.prototype.toLocaleString.call === Function.prototype.call);
```

The solution is to explicitly *give* the newly created function a calling context of the original function, which can be done with `bind`:

```js
const f = Number.prototype.toLocaleString.call.bind(Number.prototype.toLocaleString);
console.log(f(3333));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is a method (inherited from `Function.prototype.call`) and like any shared method needs to be [*bound*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to its target if you want to use it as a plain function. In this case, the target object is the `toLocaleString` function:

```js
const f = Function.prototype.call.bind(Number.prototype.toLocaleString);
console.log(f(1));
```